# Removing first element in Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list, python-3.6

```
def remove(self: 'LinkedList') -> None:
    occur = self._last
    if occur!= None:
        occur = self._first
    occur._first = None

>>> lst = LinkedList([1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1])
>>> lst.remove()
>>> lst == LinkedList([2, 1, 3, 2, 1])
```

Actual result:
True

My output:
False

Im trying to remove the first element from the linked list. Im not sure if my implementation is right

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: But you **only set the reference of `occur`** which is a local reference.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what do u mean

Comment: @TheGamer: well by setting `occur = self._last`, changes to the *reference* of `occur` will *not* reflect to `self._last` itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to **remove** the first element of a linked list, that means that `._first` should refer to the *second* element in the list from now on.

Furthermore you have to check if the `._last` element is the `._first` element. If that is the case, you have to set `._last` to `None` as well, since in that case, the list contains only one element.

So you can do this with:

```
def remove_head (self: 'LinkedList') -> None:
    # check if the list is not empty
    if self._first is not None:
        # check if first and last refer to the same node
        if self._last is self._first:
            # if so the list contains one node, so set _last to None
            self._last = None
        # update the pointer to the _first element to advance one hop
        self._first = self._first._next
```

I here made the assumption that the reference to the next node in a node is called `_next`. But you can easily alter that. You also better name your function with more descriptive names, like `remove_head`.